# What is the use of Composer SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Composer provides completely implemented `REST` server using which any `client` side application can interact with application deployed to `hyperledger fabric`. And also composer provides `SDK` to interact with deployed application. `Composer REST server` also behind the scenes uses `SDK`. Is there any specific use case of `Composer SDK`. Why don't one just simply use `Composer REST Server`.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of functionalities which aren't provided by the composer-rest-server. Achieving all those features in your application requires the use of SDK. For example you cannot create an identity card using composer rest server but the SDK allows those functionalities.

Comment: If you mean identity card as card for participants then I am able to create card with API of REST server.

Comment: Anothwr quick question, I can't use composer-client module for web application to interact with fabric runtime, only its useful for nkde.js runtime. What's the use of it If I can't interact with business network in client side web app.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want users to access my client webapp which uses `Business Network Card` of user to interact with `Fabric Runtime`. This card is accessed by `webapp` from user filesystem or User can upload this card in webapp.

Comment: Accessing from `filesystem` is not possible due to permission issues, So next solution is to use `composer-wallet-inmemory` `cardStore` but `composer-client SDK` does not have functionalities for card management. Only `composer-admin` has.